# DOJO Onblur event

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, onblur

I have a textbox with onblur event written in DOJO. In onBlur event I have to do some functionality if the textbox value has word 'AP'.But for some reason once onblur event is fired.The entire document is getting click event i.e., on clicking anypart of webpage, the onblur function is calling out.So, I used dojo.disconnect(handle) to remove the event.But, Now the problem is if user again change the textbox value, onblur event is not calling since it is disconnected.Following is my code

```
this.text = dojo.query('.state')[0];
this.handle = dojo.connect( this.text, 'onblur', this, function(){
      alert(this.text.value);
      dojo.disconnect(this.handle);
 });
```

I want to change the value of textbox again so that onblur event function should be handled

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why do you disconnect the `onblur` event handler when it fires? If the textfield has focus, and you click on anything other than the textfield, then the textfield will get an `onblur` event. Is this not to be expected?

Comment: Once the onblur event is fired, on clicking on any part of the page, it is firing onblur event.

Comment: I have started a jsfiddle for you, http://jsfiddle.net/6WxBn/. Please explain via this. This first version of the fiddle behaves as expected. If you click inside the text field, it receives focus. If you click outside the text field it receives a `blur` event and removes the event handler. No more `blur` events are received.